# Association and relationship in statistics

Tags: correlation, terminology, association-measure

I heard someone arguing in a conference that when you use the word "association" it indicates to the result of a chi-square test and when you use the word "relation" it indicates to the result of correlation. Which means when you say "there is a significant association between X and Y" it means the test conducted was Chi-Square, and when you say that there is a significant relation between X and Y the test conducted was correlation. Is this argument correct?

Comment: I don't think there's any reasonable basis for such a position. Did they give any argument to support this rather extraordinary claim?

Comment: [This thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28035/association-or-relationship) may be useful for the discussion.