# How to Reshape Linear Regression Model using Correlation Coefficient instead of slope?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, transform

I try to reproduce Results from [Harding and Pagan (2004), p.12](https://cama.crawford.anu.edu.au/sites/default/files/publication/cama_crawford_anu_edu_au/2017-02/3_paganpaper_2004.pdf), where they try to estimate the correlation coefficient $\rho_{S} = cor(S_{y,i},S_{x,i})$ using regression on

$$
\frac{S_{y,t}}{\hat{\sigma_{S_x}}\hat{\sigma_{S_y}}} = \alpha_1 + \frac{\rho_S}{\hat{\sigma_{S_x}}\hat{\sigma_{S_y}}} S_{x,t} + \varepsilon_{1,t}
$$.

But whatever I try to transform the equations for linear relation between $S_{x,t}$, $S_{x,t}$

$$
S_{y,t} = \alpha_0+\beta S_{x,t}+\varepsilon_{0,t}
$$

and the [definition of the correlation coefficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32464/how-does-the-correlation-coefficient-differ-from-regression-slope) $\hat{\beta} = \rho_S\frac{\hat{\sigma_{S_y}}}{\hat{\sigma_{S_x}}}$, I never manage to get the result in the first equation. Any ideas?

Thank's a lot!!

Comment: This is correct if both the $\beta$ and $\rho$ are estimates.

Comment: By "this" you mean the first equation? Can you point to any Source I can take further reading in?

Comment: I was talking about your claim regarding your final equation. I think you can find this in any regression book (e.g. Draper and Smith).