# Can I calculate the correlation coefficient from the beta of fixed effects in a linear mixed model?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, effect-size, partial-correlation

I would like to determine a partial correlation from fixed effects in my linear mixed models.

If i would run a model for example  $Aij = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + \beta_2Y + \beta_2Z + ui$ + ϵij

Can I calculate a partial correlation coefficient for the $\beta_1$ to $A$ using the formula

$r= \beta_1 *(var(\beta_1) / \text{sd}(A))$ ?

Comment: What information do you have available for calculating?  Because the units of your proposed formula for $r$ are incorrect, it cannot possibly be right.  (The units of $\beta_1$ are in units of $A$ per unit of $X$, so the units for your $r$ are units of $A$ per squared unit of $X,$ rather than being unitless as required of any correlation coefficient.)

Comment: This formula is the rescaling formula between the correlation coefficient and regression coeficient (see this post [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32464/how-does-the-correlation-coefficient-differ-from-regression-slope) . This is valid for a simple linear regression but is I am wondering if its valid to use in a more complex models as presented here

Comment: You haven't quoted the formula correctly.  What your readers will understand by "$\operatorname{sd}(\beta_1)$" (which makes no sense when read literally because $\beta_1$ is a *number*) is that it is the *sampling variance of the least squares estimate of $\beta_1.$*

Comment: Thank, indeed I mean the _se_ of the estimate for the ___β1___.  I will change it.

Comment: The units still are nonsensical.

Comment: How would you suggest writing it down? Might be my ignorance.

Comment: I would suggest reviewing the formulas you can [find here on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=partial+correlation+formula+is%3Aanswer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution you can consider is the `partR2` package in R (Stoffel et al., 2019). This allows you to derive a partial effect size for each fixed effects predictor. It is technically devised of two coefficients. The first is $part R^2$, defined below as:

$$
R^2_{x^*} = \frac{Y_X-Y_\tilde{X}}{Y_X+Y_{RE}+Y_R} = \frac{Y_X-Y_\tilde{X}}{Y_{Total}}
$$

where ${X}$ is the variance explained by fixed effects in a full model versus $\tilde{X}$, which is the variance in fixed effects from a reduced model. The denominator $Y_X + Y_{RE} + Y_R$ is essentially the total variance in the model (fixed effects + random effects + residuals). This effectively allows one to tease apart to a degree how much variance changes when the model is reduced down to remove the effect of other predictors. The second coefficient is $inclusive$ $R^2$, which is defined below:

$$
IR^2_{x*} = SC^2 * R^2_{x^*}
$$

where $SC^2$ is the squared correlation between a predictor of interest and a linear predictor times its $part R^2$. This coefficient quantifies the total proportion of variance explained in the model, both uniquely and jointly with other predictors.

##### Citation

Stoffel, M. A., Nakagawa, S., & Schielzeth, H. (2021). partR2: Partitioning R2 in generalized linear mixed models. PeerJ, 9, e11414. https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.11414