# How to generate a probability of x given a value of y and a distribution?

Tags: distributions, probability, python

I have a bivariate data set where x and y values, both continuous variables, correlate well (visually speaking) when x and y are small. As the values of x and y increase, the correlation decreases to an eventual random state when x and y are large. My question is, given a y value, I would like to know the probability of the value of a given x. Should I generate a probability distribution for this data?

I would very much appreciate any practical advice for Python in specific.

Comment: For any continuous distributions, the probability of any specific value is infinitesimal.

Comment: Perhaps my question is not framed correctly. Imagine if for all x values where x=1, all y values were 10. Based on this, I'd like to say, that given the distribution of the data, if y=1 the probability of x=10 is 100%.

Comment: Then the data are not continuous.

Comment: Can I not draw a value of 1 from continuous data?

Comment: Not 1 exactly, not for truly continuous data; or, rather, the chance of getting 1 exactly is infinitesimal, but not 0. 

It gets into a question of integrals vs. summation signs. 

You can say things about "1 or less", if you like.

Comment: In addition to @PeterFlom's points, I wonder if you are thinking that estimation of X values given Y & estimation of Y values given X are symmetric. Intuitively, it seems like they should be, but they aren't. You may find this interesting: [What is the difference between doing linear regression on y with x versus x with y?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22718//22721#22721).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might first explore fitting the data to a bivariate normal model.  And you'll want to evaluate  whether a bivariate model is sensible of course given your note about the decreasing correlation with larger values.  That's hard to interpret without more detail - if you have a lot of data for those higher regions then bivariate might not be a good idea, but if the data is sparse then you might remove for a cleaner model.

I suggest trying a bivariate normal model because it has several simplifications which will support your goal:

- You can fit the model by calculating just 5 simple parameters:  $\mu_X$, $\mu_Y$, $\sigma_X$, $\sigma_Y$, and the correlation coefficient $\rho$.
- And for a bivariate distribution the conditional distribution is itself a normal distribution.  Your core question -- how to state that if $y = \text{<some value>}$ then the probability of $x$ being in a range of values -- requires conditional distributions, and a normal conditional distribution is easily calculated from a bivariate normal model:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  E[X | Y = y] &= \mu_X + ( \rho * (y - \mu_Y) * (\sigma_X / \sigma_Y))  \\
  \text{Var}[X | Y = y] &= \sigma_X^2 * (1 - \rho^2)
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- With the conditional expectation and the conditional variance you now have the parameters for the (conditional) normal distribution - your new $\mu = E[X | Y=y]$ and your new stdev is equal to $\sqrt{\text{Var}[X | Y=y]}$
- And Peter Flom's point is spot on, its more intuitive to talk about the probability of $X$ being in a range of values, so specifically you want to use the **cumulative** form of the normal distribution for your conditional distribution.

Regarding the python that's harder to say without knowing what you're using - but I suspect if you're able to plot out and examine your data to draw those conclusions then you also have basic statistical commands (via scipy / numpy) and can easily calculate the 5 parameters mentioned above.  With that it's just a matter of calculating the two formulas above.

From there use something like scipy.stats to calculate the cumulative normal distribution values for given $\mu$ and stdev.  Don't try to program that function manually - it's doable but requires some rather arcane formulas!

Comment: +1, nice answer! Welcome to the site, @tabSF. You'll be happy to know that CV supports $\LaTeX$ via mathjax. I took the liberty of tweaking your answer for greater readability; make sure it still says what you want. Since you're new here, you may want to read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) as well, which covers the markup options available (among other things).

Comment: @gung, thanks for the tip and applying the latex! I will definitely check out the FAQ -- am very excited to discover this site & community.

Comment: Thanks so much! Very helpful. I do have a lot of data in the higher regions. I'll look into the CDF suggestion.