# How are "transforming the data" and GLMs different?

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I read the following: [image]
in John Fox's *Applied Regression Analysis and Generalized Linear Models.*

I don't understand this distinction.

In OLS, I have

$$E[y_i|X] = E[x_i^T\beta + \epsilon_i|X] = x_i^T\beta + E[\epsilon_i |X]= x_i^T\beta$$ 
Now suppose I have a log-linear model

$$\log(y) = X\beta + \epsilon$$

where transforming the data is similar to this case

[image]

[image]

where transforming the data leads to a linear relationship. source: https://kenbenoit.net/assets/courses/ME104/logmodels2.pdf

What do GLMs do that is different from this?

Comment: You seem to be asserting $z_i = \log(y_i) = x_i^\prime\beta + \epsilon_i = y_i$ which is impossible.  When you correctly take logarithms you obtain $z_i = \log(x_i^\prime\beta + \epsilon_i)$ but that cannot be expressed in the form $x_i^\prime \gamma + \delta_i.$

Comment: @whuber I tried to rephrase the question. Let me know if it's still nonsensical.

Comment: Doesn't https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29325/ answer your question?  Perhaps https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43930 adds a little something to that.  Check out [our other highly-voted threads on GLM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=glm), too.

Comment: @whuber Your comments on one of the answers in the second link you posted touch on something I'm confused about. In OLS, the estimator $\hat{\beta}$ is derived from the data via a closed form solution. I don't understand why for GLM we are concerned with $E[y_i]$ instead of $y_i$.  Do we treat each observation as a random variable? If so, why would we need to make that specific for each observation? If each $y_i$ is drawn from the same distribution, why wouldn't there just be one mean (i.e. the mean for that distribution)?

Comment: In order: yes; because the observations are independent; yes.

Comment: @whuber ok thanks! i think you can close this as a duplicate of the second link you gave then. I can also delete it if thats preferred.