# In a linear regression, how do I find the predictor for which the response is zero?

Tags: regression

I'm linearly regressing some response `y` onto some predictor `x`. I'm interested in knowing for what `x` does `y = 0`.

I can think of two ways to do this. Let me illustrate with some sample data:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 20 - 2 * x + rnorm(10)
```

I can either linearly regress `y` onto `x` and solve the equation explicitly:

```
- coef(lm(y ~ x))[1] / coef(lm(y ~ x))[2]
(Intercept) 
   10.29915
```

Or I can try to be clever and observe that my problem is equivalent to regressing `x` onto `y` and predicting `x` for `y = 0`:

```
coef(lm(x ~ y))[1]
(Intercept) 
   10.19658
```

However, this doesn't give quite the same result. So which approach is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is correct, as regressing $y$ on $x$ is not equivalent to regressing $x$ on $y$. The error terms in each model are different. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22718/) for a thorough explanation.