# Relationships of two regressional coefficients

Tags: regression, variance

I have two one dimensional dataset $X$ and $Y$.

I run regression and obtained $A$ from $Y = AX$. And another regression and obtain $B$ from $X = BY$. What's the relationship between $A$ and $B$? Is it always $A = 1/B$? My computer simulation suggests otherwise...

Comment: Are you talking about simple regression? Does your regression have an intercept or is this regression through the origin? (And where's your error term? Or is that intended to be an equation for $\hat{Y}$?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple regression, $y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x+\epsilon$, $\hat{\beta}_1=r\frac{s_y}{s_x}$.

By symmetry, for $x=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 y+\eta$, $\hat{\alpha}_1=r\frac{s_x}{s_y}$.

Clearly, then,  ${\hat{\alpha_1}}= \frac{r^2}{\hat{\beta_1}}$, which is always $\leq \frac{1}{\hat{\beta_1}}$.

See the additional information in gung's excellent answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22721/805). It doesn't directly answer this question, but it provides you with a lot of the tools and intuition that's useful for taking the extra small steps from that answer.