# standardised random variable least square regression $X$ against $Y$, $Y$ against $X$

Tags: regression, least-squares

Let $X$ and $Y$ be mean 0 and variance 1 random variables such that we choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to minimise

$$\mathbb{E}(X-\beta Y)^2$$

and

$$\mathbb{E}(Y-\alpha X)^2$$

after not so difficult derivation, I arrive at $\alpha = \mathbb{E}(XY)/\mathbb{E}X^2$ and $\beta = \mathbb{E}(XY)/\mathbb{E}Y^2$, so $\alpha = \beta$.

This seems very strange, because if $y=mx$ is regression line, then surely $x = \frac{1}{m }y$.

Comment: (X - Y)^2 = (Y - X)^2 for each X and Y. Basically it's the same function (expand the expressions for prove). That's why you get alpha = beta

Comment: @Ivan sorry, you are going too fast for me. How are they the same function? The coefficient is in front of $X$ in one of the expression and $Y$ in the other.

Comment: that's minimization problem. In best case you have
E(X - \betaY)^2 = 0
expanding the expression
X^2 - 2X\betaY + Y^2 = 0
\beta = (X^2 - 2xy + y^2)
and
E(Y-\alphaX)^2 = 0
\alpha = (Y^2 - 2xy + X^2)
witch is basically the same

Comment: @Ivan when you expand you should get $X^2+2\beta XY +\beta^2 Y^2$? why has the beta's disappeared? I do not follow this.

Comment: @ChristophHanck I don't get what you are saying. What are you trying to answer?

Comment: @ChristophHanck Homework?! lol. I am a PhD student... I have already figured out $\alpha=\beta$. My question is that why is this the case, this seems counter intuitive for the reason I have given, $y=mx$ should imply $x=\frac{1}{m} y$ Maybe, I should have deleted the sentence "have I calculated $\alpha$ and $\beta$ wrong?$

Comment: Or maybe in such hypothesis that $1/m=m$ ? Like with two similar distributions on which you have very few but similar infomation, such that they would be approximated with X=Y, because $1=\frac{1}{1}$

Comment: What do you precisely mean by "because if $y=mx$ is regression line, then surely $x = \frac{1}{m }y$". Is it to say that, if $\hat\beta$ is the regression coefficient of a regression of $y$ on $x$, $\hat\beta^{-1}$ is the coefficient of the regression of $x$ on $y$?

Comment: Here is a simple a counterexample, (X,Y) jointly Gaussian with mean 0 and variance 1, correlation $\rho$ for any $\rho$... Please do not pose comments as answers.

Comment: @ChristophHanck that would seem natural, since the line is chosen to minimise the sum of square of distance of 'points' to the line. This "minimislng line", to me, seems unique. so why is the coefficient not related in this simple manner? obviously, there is something wrong this logic here, but I cannot quite pin down exactly what is wrong.

Comment: See related discussion here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22718/67799

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will answer my own question. The reason the two regression lines are different is this:

The regression line of $Y$ against $X$ minimises the total squared distance of the $Y$ COORDINATES to the $y$ COORDINATES of the line, where as $X$ against $Y$ minimise the total squared distance of $X$ COORDINATES to the $x$ COORDINATES line.

The confusion I had with regards to the line should be unique comes from the mistaken assumption the regression line minimise the total squared (PERPENDICULAR) distance of each point to the regression line. If this had been the case, my assumption would have been true. However, the two measure of distance never coincide unless there is perfect correlation.

Comment: I think @Christoph Hanck's link provides the answer.

Comment: @mr.rox well, ive realised before i saw the link. it doesn't matter any more.