# Generate two variables with heteroscedastic residuals and a linear regression slope of 1

Tags: r, regression, residuals, heteroscedasticity, random-generation

I have a vector A, which comprises predefined revenue values of 1000 companies. Now I want to generate another vector B, which comprises the companies' revenue of the previous year. The intention is to model B by taking A as the expected value and a standard deviation that increases with the size of A: That is, larger companies have larger absolute differences between A and B than smaller companies. The purpose is to achieve a relation so that a linear regression of the **predictor B** on the **dependent variable A** would yield a line with a slope of close to 1. Hence, the relation **should** look as follows:

```
lm(A~B)$coefficients  # should yield  
                      #(Intercept)          B 
                      #     0               1
plot(B,A)
abline(lm(A~B)$coefficients, col = "red")`
```

[image]

I tried it as follows:

```
set.seed(123)
A <- 1:1000
B <- rnorm(n=1000, mean = A, sd=0.4*A)
```

However, for `lm(A~B)`:

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)          A
197.5979             0.6013
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix the generation of vector B from A, so that a linear regression of B on A would yield a slope of 1?

Comment: Does it have to be *exactly* one or is approximately (like 1.0076) good enough?

Comment: Approximately like 1.0076 is definitely enough. However, it is important that B is the predictor and A the dependent variable and that B has to be generated from A before.

Comment: Do you want to include the possibility of negative revenues in your simulation? Note that you have them now. Although I don't work in economics or business, I wouldn't think of revenues as being normally distributed, but probably something skewed & w/ fat tails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.  The thing you need to remember is that regression minimizes the *vertical* distances of the data to the line.  That is, we think of the errors as being in the response (see my answer here: [What is the difference between linear regression on y with x and x with y?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22721/7290)).  You just need to switch around which variable is your response here.  Consider:

```
set.seed(123)
A <- 1:1000
B <- rnorm(n=1000, mean = A, sd=0.4*A)
summary(lm(A~B))$coefficients  # this is your regression
#                Estimate Std. Error  t value      Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 197.5978552 9.62892402 20.52128  2.361529e-78
# B             0.6012796 0.01535132 39.16794 5.465950e-204
summary(lm(B~A))$coefficients
#               Estimate  Std. Error     t value      Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) -0.5542773 14.86392934 -0.03729009  9.702612e-01
# A            1.0076260  0.02572579 39.16793538 5.465950e-204

windows()
  # plot(B,A)  # this is your plot
  plot(A,B)    # here I switched X & Y
  abline(0,1, col="red")
  abline(coef(lm(B~A)), col="blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In order to take an estimate for $b$ equal to one you have to change the standard deviation. I used your code and I just changed it. Look at this:

```
set.seed(123)
A <- 1:1000
B <- rnorm(n=1000, mean = A, sd=1/A)

lm(A~B)

    Call:
lm(formula = A ~ B)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            B  
 -0.0003096    1.0000004

lm(B~A)

Call:
lm(formula = B ~ A)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            A  
  0.0003144    0.9999996
```

I suppose that this is what you want.
Note that you will take similar results in case of using standard deviation $sd = A^k$, for each $k$ not zero of course.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your reply and adjustment! However, the purpose is that the standard deviation of B increases with A as displayed in the illustration above. With your hint of sd=1/A, the opposite is the case.  My fault, I probably didn't make that intention clear enough and will edit it in the question. I also tried sd=A^k, with (among others) k=0.8, which lead to the same problem of lm(A~B) yielding a slope of far below 1.