# Relationship between two randomly-generated variables

Tags: regression, econometrics, random-variable, stata, uniform-distribution

Using stata, I generate two random variables and regress them with each other.

```
clear
set obs 1000
gen rand1 = uniform()
gen rand2 = uniform()
reg rand1 rand2, nocons
reg rand2 rand1, nocons
```

And I found weird patterns.

1. How can both regressions have coefficient smaller than 1? Intuitively I can't get it.
2. Why are coefficients from both regressions always smaller than 1?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22718.  Notice, too, that the formula for the slope estimate is a ratio of random variables.  The expectation of the numerator is $1/4$ and that of the denominator is $1/3,$ implying that with large samples (and 1000 is sufficiently large) the expectation of the slope estimate will be close to $1/4/(1/3) = 3/4.$

Comment: Re (2): it's not always the case that both coefficient estimates are less than $1.$  This becomes clear when you use a smaller value of `obs`.  Indeed, with `obs` set to `1`, the expected value of either regression coefficient is *infinite!*

Answer (score 2):

Note that omitting the intercept the estimate for the coefficient $\beta$ is given by <[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Simple_linear_regression_without_the_intercept_term_(single_regressor))>

$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum^n_{i=1} x_iy_i}{\sum^n_{i=1}x_i^2}$

in other words dividing the sum of $x$ times $y$ by the sum of squares of $x$ $-$ can also take the mean. 
Due to the random ordering matching $x$ and $y$ values in the linear model you end up with a smaller numerator and as a result your coefficient will be smaller than 1.

I must admit that this is probably not an entirely satisfactory answer as it is based mainly on observed patterns; I don't know if there is a better mathematical explanation for it. You can check the former for yourself though. 
Just take the sum of $xy$ as they were generated and compare it with the sum when you order both variables (dividing them by the sum of squares of $x$).

Comment: Hi: Note that the coefficient of the regression based on $y \sim x$ is not one over the coefficient of the regression based on $x \sim y$, if that's why you're puzzled by why they are both less than 1.0.

Comment: @mlofton   I know that. But if the line emanating from (0,0) is lower than 45 degree line, I am wondering about the condition under which the opposite could be also lower than 45 degree line.

Comment: The mathematical explanation is cauchy schwarz inequality/chebyshev inequality

Comment: @user42459: Pig is probably correct but  the easiest thing to do would be to just calculate $\hat{\beta}$ in both cases. You have the data and the formula.