# Standardized bivariate linear regression coefficients > 1?

Tags: regression, standardization

x and y are two columns of financial data which have been standardized. Assuming one implements a simple linear regression on x and y, is it possible to observe a slope greater than 1?

I ran some numbers in Excel and cannot get the slope to ever exceed 1. Can someone please explain the mathematical reason why this is impossible?

Comment: When both variables are standardized, the slope is the same as pearson's correlation which is always smaller than 1 in magnitude. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22718/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-regression-on-y-with-x-and-x-with-y/22721#22721)

Comment: But why is that the case?

Comment: It's a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality (or any equivalent inequality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [well known result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Fitting_the_regression_line) that the slope of a simple linear regresison is

$$\hat{\beta_1} = r_{xy} \dfrac{s_y}{s_x}$$

Here $r_{xy}$ is the sample correlation coefficient and $s_x, s_y$ are the sampel standard deviations of $x$ and $y$.  The result is obtained immediately when you realize that standardization fixes $s_x=s_y=1$.